# $(doucment).ready(function(){}); and $(window).load(function() {}); confusion

Tags: jquery, function, image-resizing, document-ready

My test product page over at http://www.marioplanet.com/product.htm has some odd behaviors which I could really use some help working out.

Now, I had a problem previously with my image resizing, and someone here helped me out by saying that I should nest the image resize inside a

```
$(window).load(function(){});
```

In order for the images to load before the resize occurs, so that the resize wouldn't find an incorrect width and height, since it wouldn't have loaded yet, instead of nesting it within the document ready function.

Now that I have done this, I'm wondering what I should do with the jQuery that is nested within my document ready function, as it is the fancybox jQuery plugin, and it doesn't appear to be functioning correctly.

If I move the fancybox jQuery from the document ready to the window load function, for some reason, none of it works!

I could really use some help here, so any info or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Just as a side note, it would be nice to figure out how to make the images not load at all, and just load once the scaled-down effect was applied to the images, so the images don't show up big and then out of nowhere, shrink down.

Comment: The word `set` is in your code on line 25: `'transitionIn' : 'elastic', set`. This is causing your code to have a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you so so much. Arghh, so many little errors! :)

Comment: No worries. To load the images "shrunk", you could specify the width in a css class instead of setting the width when the document loads.

Comment: You mean, bypassing the jQuery all together? That would be better anyway.  So, it's possible to define percentages that say shrink the image to 25% of its original size, just replicating my jQuery snippet entirely?

Comment: Yep. It's as easy as you think it would be. For example, in your css file, you could do `img.FancyBox { width: 25%; }` :)

Comment: Haha, I figured it would be. I just tried it, but for some reason, it gets all screwy, and sizes them way down..

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready(...);` is for when `DOMContentLoaded` is called. This happens after the DOM is fully created, but before images and other externals are finished downloading. After that happens, `load` is triggered, which can be listened for via `$(window).load(...);`. Please [don't use jQuery](http://azabani.com/articles/dependence) for something as simple as this!

Comment: I realized this, as Nate helped me point that out, using CSS is waay better in this case, but for some reason, it won't work.  I have it currently specified to have the width and height be 25% but that didn't work, and only setting the width to 25% doesn't work either.